# Is there a way to redeem the serverAuthCode in a standard HTTPS request?

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

The docs at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/offline-access show how to get a `serverAuthCode` in Swift.

This allows your own server to redeem this code for an Oauth access token and make API requests to Google on behalf of the user.

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) 
    let code = user.serverAuthCode
    // send it to the server
}
```

However, the guide only demonstrates the server-side part of the process in Java or Python.

Would it be possible to redeem this `serverAuthCode` using an HTTPS request only - without the Java/Python libraries. If so, how could this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ["OAuth 2.0 for Web Server"](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server) guide available from Google seems to work for redeeming the `serverAuthCode` generated by the iOS library.

The section titled **"Step 5: Exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens"** documents the simple process.

Despite the fact it asks for a `redirect_uri` this doesn't matter as it just needs to be registered with Google and no redirect actually occurs.